# std::mem_fn for a class member won't compile

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I am trying to use function pointers to own member functions in my class, using C++11 and MSVC2013.

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
    // ...
    QColor Colorize(double dValue) const;

private:
    bool m_bUseColor1;
    QColor Color1(double dValue) const;
    QColor Color2(double dValue) const;
};
```

Implementation

```
QColor MyClass::Colorize(double dValue) const
{
    auto colorize_func =  m_bUseColor1 ? std::mem_fn(&MyClass::Color1) : std::mem_fn(&MyClass::Color2);

    QColor myColor =  colorize_func(23.3);// FAILS TO COMPILE
}
```

This gives the following errors:

> Error  102 error C2100: illegal indirection    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xrefwrap 311
>   Error   103 error C2296: '.*' : illegal, left operand has type 'double' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xrefwrap 311

Any ideas what is going wrong here? I followed the syntax of [cppreference `mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) but obviously there is an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of `colorize_func(23.3)` requires an instance of the class `MyClass` to compile and run. Not just the argument for the function.

E.g.:

```
MyClass mc;
// ....
colorize_func(mc, 23.3);
```

Since the use of `colorize_func` is already in a member function, you can use `this` as well.

```
QColor myColor =  colorize_func(this, 23.3);
```

Should do it.

The code is all part of the member anyway, it could also be possible to simplify the code to;

```
QColor MyClass::Colorize(double dValue) const
{
  return (m_bUseColor ? Color1(dValue) : Color2(dValue));
}
```

---

A note on [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) and it's use (quotes from cppreference.com);

> Function template `std::mem_fn` generates wrapper objects for pointers to members, which can store, copy, and invoke a pointer to member. Both references and pointers (including smart pointers) to an object can be used when invoking a `std::mem_fn`.

In all cases, the first (or only) argument provided to the callable wrapper is a pointer or reference to an instance of the class.

> `first_argument_type` `T*` if `pm` is a pointer to member function taking one argument

These requirements are similar to the older [`std::mem_fun`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fun) and [`std::mem_fun_ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fun_ref) and how they were used.

Comment: Usual notation is `this->*colorize_func(23.3)`

Comment: @TobySpeight. That is the notation for when `colorize_func` is a normal member function pointer. In this is it not, it is an object (of unspecified type) that can be used to call a member function.

Comment: @Niall - er, yes, you're completely right.  And right that the object to bind the function to should be the first argument to the functor call.  Thanks for picking me up on that!

Comment: You might want to quote from [C++ reference site](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/mem_fun/), where the return value of `std::mem_fun` is described as " A function object which calls the member function f of the *object whose pointer is passed as the (first) argument*.
If the member function accepts one parameter, this is specified as the second argument in the function object." (my emphasis)